# Slider Revolution Custom Css not working

Tags: css, wordpress, layer, revolution-slider

im currently setting up a new website and im working with the avada theme + slider revolution. I have a Mainpage-Slider with some layer on top. I tried to set the opacity of that overlay-layers (picture) to 0.5 with a custom css code.

`{opacity: 0.5;}`

The code worked in the preview/editing window but not on the website itself. How can I solve that problem?

Furthermore, the style display mode is the set to Block not to inline. Do I cant change that?! is that connected to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can best load your custom css after plugin's css.
This way you overwrite it.

You can also try this:

```
{opacity: 0.5 !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks für your anwser wimanicesir :) unfortunately its not working. When i add the !improtant, the effect of the opacity is gone also in the preview. I tried to change the loading sequence with code in the layer css but it wont work. Where do i have to change the sequence?

Comment: In your head section, the order you load the CSS is important. 
So <link rel="stylesheet" .... CSS PLUGIN>  should go before <link rel="stylesheet .. OWN CSS/>. That's what I mean with changing the sequence.